# How can I vertically center an element if it's parent has responsive height?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I have an element which I want to take up the lower half of the screen, at least, but still allow text to make it larger. Naturally, I would use min-height, but that seems to fail when it comes to vertically centering the text within.

I can't use `position:absolute` because it needs to remain in the DOM.

Here is a mockup of the situation:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
.img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.text {
  min-height: 20%;
  background: coral;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15%;
}
.centered {
  /* I need to center this within it's parent */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="centered">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec blandit mauris vel libero pretium viverra. Mauris  tristique nisl erat, convallis suscipit lacus consectetur ac. Ut pretium lorem odio, quis feugiat erat ultrices finibus. Curabitur nec suscipit felis. Ut at iaculis nisl, quis aliquet tellus. Aliquam eu massa velit. Etiam et ultricies velit. Ut et tortor feugiat, laoreet lacus et, faucibus turpis. Aliquam pretium elit ut nisl pellentesque, quis aliquet ante varius. Etiam sit amet elementum odio. Donec vulputate est at gravida faucibus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you read your post first related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I did. Either the solutions require fixed height, or they require `position:absolute` (I have text so that won't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
.img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.text {
  min-height: 20%;
  background: coral;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15%;
  display: table;
}
.centered {
  /* I need to center this within it's parent */
  display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text">
<div class="centered">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec blandit mauris vel libero pretium viverra. Mauris  tristique nisl erat, convallis suscipit lacus consectetur ac. Ut pretium lorem odio, quis feugiat erat ultrices finibus. Curabitur nec suscipit felis. Ut at iaculis nisl, quis aliquet tellus. Aliquam eu massa velit. Etiam et ultricies velit. Ut et tortor feugiat, laoreet lacus et, faucibus turpis. Aliquam pretium elit ut nisl pellentesque, quis aliquet ante varius. Etiam sit amet elementum odio. Donec vulputate est at gravida faucibus.</p>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I had hoped to avoid using tables, but it seems that's the only way. Oh well!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with `display: flex` and some padding. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jos5khxo/).

Comment: I may have posted my answer too quickly because padding alone on the top and bottom also does the trick.

Comment: I prefer to not use flex. Wish I could!

Comment: Padding on the top and bottom fails when the min-height kicks into effect.

Comment: I'm not seeing where it fails. Can you include a screenshot and let me know at what browser width it fails?

Comment: When the element is resizing to the text, it looks fine (when it is greater than 20%). However, when the text has excess room, only the top padding is used, and the rest of the element is just a big space. I do have screenshots, if you still need them.

Comment: Still not seeing this. Please let me know what browser you are using, the browser width where you see this fail, and a link to a screen shot. I was out for a few days but will get right back to you. Thanks!

Comment: This happens on every browser. [Here's the screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/RhPfQ), the first is when the window is zoomed normally (the text is resizing the container) and the second is when the min-height is dictating the height (the text is too spread out to have an effect, so only the top padding works).

Comment: Very sorry but I am not able to duplicate what you are seeing. If you are working locally, there is probably a conflict but without seeing all the code, I can only guess. Something appears to be overriding your `padding` when `min-height` kicks in. I'd try modifying the code in my fiddle to `padding: 30px !important;` to see if that solves it. If so, then it's just a matter of tracking down the conflict. If that doesn't work, turn off `min-height` to see if the same thing happens– if so, then you have another bug to track down. Sorry I wasn't able to fully resolve this for you.

Comment: Not a problem, I was able to find a better situation. This is a really weird occurrence though, if you're not seeing it, are you using this code when testing? http://jsfiddle.net/jos5khxo/2/